# Multiplying/Dividing Given an array of operators and an array of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, math

The Task: Given an array of characters with either '*' or '/' (call this the operator array) and an array of floats, multiply/divide the numbers in the order of the characters in the operator array. The last entry in the array should contain the final answer while the rest of the indices are null.

Let's say you have 1/2*3*4/5*6
The number array would be [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0] and the operator array would be [/, * ,*,/, * ]. I am getting an index out of bounds error for the line nums[i] = null but I do not understand why (because if I am getting an index out of bounds error for nums[i] why am I not getting it for nums[i++]?).

ops is the operators array and nums is the numbers array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ops.length; i++){
    if(ops[i] == '*') {
       nums[i++] = nums[i]*nums[i++];
       nums[i] = null;
     }else if(ops[i] == '/') {
       nums[i++] = nums[i]/nums[i++];
       nums[i] = null;
     }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this does not address order of operations, but since you are only dealing with division and multiplication (they are associative) it still works.

Initialize the result with the first number, then loop over the remaining numbers and use the appropriate operator to compute the current number with the running result.

```
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] numbers = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 };
        String[] operators = { "/", "*", "*", "/", "*" };

        System.out.println(compute(numbers, operators)); // 1 ÷ 2 * 3 * 4 ÷ 5 * 6 = 7.2
    }

    private static double compute(double[] numbers, String[] operators) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (operators.length != numbers.length - 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("operator count must be one less than number count");
        }
        double result = numbers[0];
        if (numbers.length > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                switch (operators[i - 1]) {
                    case "+":
                        result += numbers[i];
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result -= numbers[i];
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result *= numbers[i];
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        result /= numbers[i];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`i++` returns the value of `i` for the expression, then after the evaluation of the expression increments `i`.

You most likely want to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ops.length; i++){
    if(ops[i] == '*') {
       nums[i+1] = nums[i]*nums[i+1];
       nums[i] = null;
     }else if(ops[i] == '/') {
       nums[i+1] = nums[i]/nums[i+1];
       nums[i] = null;
    }
}
```

You are incrementing `i` before you should because of these.

Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) for more information on postfix/prefix increment(++).

Answer (score 0):

If your array of characters only contains either '*' or '/', you can use the 
      below code to reduce the number of lines of code

```
  //Usage of Ternary Operator
  for(int i = 0; i < ops.length; i++){
          nums[i+1] = ops[i]=='*'?  nums[i] * nums[i+1]: nums[i]/nums[i+1];  
          nums[i]=null;
   }
```